# How to correct change querySelector to querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Before me the developer created the next chunk of code for marking the focused of the form field:

```
function focusIt(elem) {
    var label = document.querySelector('label[for="' + elem.getAttribute('id') + '"]')

    if (label !== null) {
        label.classList.remove('unfocus-label')
        if ((jQuery(elem).hasClass('wpcf7-textarea') && (jQuery('.embedded-to-description').length))) {
            var fileArea = jQuery('.embedded-to-description')
            fileArea.addClass('small')
        }
    }
}
```

And it works well until we add a new form to this page with the as we know the querySelector returns the first element within the document that matches the specified selector. So the second form does not work (field focusing).

I treid to change the code for this variant:

```
function focusIt(elem) {
    var label = document.querySelectorAll('label[for="' + elem.getAttribute('id') + '"]')

    if (label !== null) {
        label.forEach(item => {
          item.classList.remove('unfocus-label')
        });
        if ((jQuery(elem).hasClass('wpcf7-textarea') && (jQuery('.embedded-to-description').length))) {
            var fileArea = jQuery('.embedded-to-description')
            fileArea.addClass('small')
        }
    }
}
```

But it also does not work properly.  Please help me rebuilt this code for correct way.

Sorry guys, I forget share the chunk of code where this function  get called from. Here is this code:

```
var formInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.wpcf7-form-control')
        try {
            for (var m = 0; m < formInputs.length; m++) {
                var input = formInputs[m]
                unfocusIt(input)
                input.addEventListener('focus', function () {
                    focusIt(this)
                })
                input.addEventListener('blur', function () {
                    unfocusIt(this)
                })
            }

        } catch (e) {
            console.log('not supported')
            jQuery('.label').addClass('unfocus-label')
        }
```

Comment: Where does this function get called from, and what gets passed in for the `elem` parameter?

Comment: Remove the redundant `if (label !== null)` check and your code will work as it is.

Comment: querySelectorAll returns an array, so at minimum you'd need to change the code to iterate over that array.  But you shouldn't need querySelectorAll here, that selector should only match one element unless both your forms have the same ID (which they shouldn't). Go back to using querySelector.

Comment: `elem.getAttribute('id')` - if you're returning multiple labels, then it's because you have multiple elements with the same ID - and *that's* where your problem is.

Comment: Tagged and using jquery, so why not use jquery and not worry about?   `$('label[for="' + elem.id + '"]').removeClass("unfocus-label")`

Comment: @CBroe Hi, thanks for notice, I really forgot to add the code where function get called from. Now I added it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to SO !

As you mentioned `querySelector` does indeed select the first occurence of the specified selector, since your targeting a `label[for="yourElementId"]` it should work as intended with 2 distinct forms as you request it dynamically (so you should have something like `id="my-form-1` and `id="my-form-2`), the fact that is seems not to be the case is that you use the same `id` for your second form which is wrong as you should never have more than one `id` into your page.

My suggestion is to check your html for duplicate id and change them so they are unique within a same page :)

Comment: I understand your point, yet from the OP post I understand that the first form still get the focus when clicking on the second, if the selector are clearly distinct then it shouldn't happens, should it ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I checked selectors, and I see it is really diff.